# sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-restore

how to restore deleted row from particular table .?

i have tranct log file

Answer (score 1):

You can use various utilities to read through the Transaction Log file and recover the data for you. Have a read of [this article](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-recover-data-from-sql-server-s-log-files.html) which gives a good overview of the process with links to the utils.